# Is there any tool I can use to examine the differences between two OCR pdfs?

Tags: pdf, software

I have pdf's to two solutions manuals for a textbook, and I'm trying to determine how much they differ by analyzing both copies with some sort of tool. Does such a thing exist? Is there any other way of determining the differences between two OCR PDF documents?

Answer (score 2):

I've done it by converting each PDF to Word, for which there are a bunch of free converters online. Then I use Word's file comparison feature to see the differences: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306484

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be Acrobat (Pro), which has a compare function.

If it is for comparing the results of the OCR process, you might export both documents to Text, and use a text editor which has a compare function (such as Textwrangler or BBEdit).

Answer (score 1):

Use `diffpdf` on linux. You can download a Ubuntu live CD and use that, but since `diffpdf` is not included in the default install you have to install it with the software center